# Directory replacement in cmd empty folder removal

Tags: cmd

At the moment I am developing a script to copy a user's data (delimiting some file types) to a temp data location, then filtering out the empty folders in the copy. I am fine with getting the data TO the temp, and I have a script to remove empty directories, however the script scans the WHOLE of C:\ (the user that is logged in). Below is my script:

```
FOR /F delims^= %A IN ('DIR/AD/B/S^|SORT/R') DO RD "%A"
```

How would I be able to make the script scan a certain directory structure for the empty folders instead of the whole drive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can tell `dir` where to start:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /AD/B/S "C:\Users\MyName\" ^|SORT /R') DO RD "%%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this script in a specific folder and it will delete all empty folder at current level and all subfolders as well.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR/AD/B/S ^|SORT/R') DO RD "%%A"
```

Comment: I know that would work, but i would have to add some more lines of code to my batch. I would prefer to keep the code size as small as possible. Thanks anyway

Comment: What do you mean by saying " i would have to add some more lines of code to my batch" ? The code is the only one line, the same size as yours example. Now you can change yours to this one and you will have what you asked in the first place.

Comment: This PORTION of script is a part of a batch, which is based to run on the D:\ drive. This means I would have to change the drive to C:\ than use cd to change the directory to the %TEMP% (which is where the data is being backed up), than after it has deleted empty directories, I would than need to change the dive BACK to D:\. That code is not a necessity in the script. As I said, I want to keep it as small as possible.